# Detect Touches on SKNode in Array

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, touches, sknode

I have the following function which spawns squares and adds them to an array of squares. This adds new squares indefinitely until the function is stopped. The array of squares is declared in the `SKScene` like so: `var rsArray = [RedSquare]()`.

```
func spawnRedSquares() {
    if !self.gameOver {
        let rs = RedSquare()
        var rsSpawnRange = self.frame.size.width/2
        rs.position = CGPointMake(rsSpawnRange, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) + rs.sprite.size.height * 2)
        rs.zPosition = 3
        self.addChild(rs)
        self.rsArray.append(rs)

        let spawn = SKAction.runBlock(self.spawnRedSquares)
        let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(timeBetweenRedSquares))
        let spawnThenDelay = SKAction.sequence([delay, spawn])
        self.runAction(spawnThenDelay)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the `touchesBegan()` function to detect when a specific square in the array is tapped and then access the properties of the square. I can't figure out how to determine which square is being touched. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question by experimenting, and decided that I would post the answer in case anyone else had a similar problem. The code that I needed inside the `touchesBegan()` function was the following:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let rsCurrent = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        for RedSquare in rsArray {
            let rsBody = RedSquare.sprite.physicsBody
                if rsBody == rsCurrent.physicsBody?  {
                    //Action when RedSquare is touched
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give each of the squares you spawn a unique name and check that name in touchesBegan. You can use a counter and do

```
rs.name = "square\(counter++)"
```

In touchesBegan you can retrieve the name of the touched node and check it against the names of the nodes in the array.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to give the `rs node` a name. For example

```
rs.name = "RedSquare"
```

Then you can use the `nodeAtPoint` function to find the node at a particular touch point. If the node is a `RedSquare`, you can modify it.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in touches {

        let touchPoint = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(touchPoint)

        if node.name == "RedSquare" {
            // Modify node
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I can't seem to get this to work. I tried adding the name `"RedSquare"` in either the `spawnRedSquares` function or in the `RedSquare` class, but either way, nothing happens when a tap occurs.